# Disable iPhone Yahoo contacts sync

Tags: sync, itunes, iphone, address-book

Every time I plug in my iPhone, iTunes pops up a dialog asking for sync with Yahoo contacts. after I cancel, it pops up again, for 4-5 more times. But the 'Sync Yahoo!Address Book contacts' option is disabled in iTunes and I definitely don't want this to happen.

If there any way to tell iTunes to stop trying to sync with Yahoo?

Answer (score 0):

go in itunes, then click on your phones icon on the left then click on the upper tabs look for contacts and un select where its importing it from.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your Yahoo! e-mail account setup? Go into the e-mail account settings and disable the contacts option.